# google maps cannot show in jQuery accordion properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have jQuery accordion which has two panels. in side each of them, I want to show google map with gps locations. only first one, it shows properly, second one is showing mark with empty google map. please help me. thanks in advance.[show google map incorrect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD8fy.png) [this is proper showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3zK.png)

```js
         for (var k=0;k<count;k++)
         {
             var map_object = document.getElementById("map_canvas_"+array_merchants[k]);
             var mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(map_object);
             var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(geoCenter_lat,geoCenter_long);
             mapCanvas.setCenter(mapCenter);
             mapCanvas.setZoom(16);
             mapCanvas.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);

             var initPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lats[k],longs[k]);
             var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content :  "United",
                maxWidth: 100
              }); 
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : initPos,
                map : mapCanvas,
                clickable : true
              });
             infoWnd.open(null, marker);             
         }
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and to solve it i put a div inside infowondow and declare height for it.
It's not the best solution but can solve it.

Comment: This is a common problem with tabs, please search for a duplicate.  If you can't find a duplicate please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Can you show me example of your soloution? Femando

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<div id='content'>
     <h1 id='firstHeading'>Title</h1>
     <div id='bodyContent'>
         <p><b>Title2:</b> description </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

and css like this:

```
    .content {
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    #firstHeading {
        margin: 5px;
    }

    #bodyContent {
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

        #bodyContent p {
            padding: 5px;
        }
```